# COUNT (DISTINCT table_name) keyword not working with OleDB

Tags: sql, excel, count

I have one table in Excel, six columns named TOP1, TOP2, ... TOP6.

I want to get TOP1 column as distinct TOP1 values and each record's count. All records are integers.

For example, if record "100" in the column appears six times, I want to get it as

```
100, 6
200, 3
```

ect.

```
"SELECT COUNT (TOP1) FROM [Sheet1$]"
"SELECT DISTINCT TOP1 FROM [Sheet1$]"
```

works fine. But even

```
"SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT TOP1) FROM [Sheet1$]"
```

doesn't. There is some questions here but I couldn't make it.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ? What was the error message ?

Comment: Sorry I was in a hurry, totally forgot. It gives "syntax error missing operator in query expression ('COUNT (DISTINCT TOP1)')"

Comment: are you using `MS-ACCESS` ?

Comment: No, Excel. SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE statements worked fine but this did not.

Comment: SELECT TOP1, COUNT(TOP1) as n FROM [Sheet1$] group by TOP1

Comment: @TimWilliams That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Ms-Access` does not support `COUNT (DISTINCT columnname)` syntax . Use a derived table to get the count

```
select count(top1)
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT TOP1 FROM [Sheet1$]
) a
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT TOP1, COUNT(TOP1) as cnt 
FROM [Sheet1$] 
group by TOP1
```

Comment: I will try as soon as possible

Comment: That worked but I wanted it to be like 
`100, 6`
`200, 3`